# Google cloud datastore Rollback its previous saved row

Tags: django, google-cloud-datastore

I am using Django with Google cloud datastore i.e.  Djange (https://djangae.org/) 
I am new to these tech stacks and currently facing one strange issue. 
when I persist data by calling Model.save(commit=true) . The data gets saved into cloud datastore but after 4/5 mins it gets reverted.

To test it further I tried to directly change the value in database but it also got reverted after sometime. 
I am kind of confused as there is no error or exception I see . I am making atomit transaction and wrapped my code with try except to catch any exception but no luck. 
could someone please advise me as how to debug further here.

Comment: I got some lead here. well I was pointing datastore with multiple versions of code and few of them were in infinite loop to hit the same Kind of datastore. currently killing all stale version makes the DB consistent with changes. . wanted to  update so that others can get an idea if something similar happens

Comment: Please, add that comment as an answer and mark it as correct so other can see that there is a solution easily. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

I got some lead here. well I was pointing datastore with multiple versions of code and few of them were in infinite loop to hit the same Kind of datastore. currently killing all stale version makes the DB consistent with changes. . wanted to update so that others can get an idea if something similar happen